# Typical cycletime of an industry pid controller for servomotors

Tags: control-engineering

I am wondering the following. What are the typical cycletimes (or timesteps), that are used in real industry-standard pid-controllers (for example for assembly-robots on a car-production-line). I didnt find anything specific in the literature, just the theory. Therefore I am asking here. Often, these information is not published by the vendors of these pid-servo-controllers, so maybe someone has some experience here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being at all facetious, it's the cycle time the engineer in charge of the control loop felt was best.

It depends on the size of the motor, the requirements of the loop, the sophistication of the computing hardware, and how the motor is controlled.  I've written motor control loops with a cycle time of 100Hz, driving a current command to a transresistance amplifier.  I've written motor control loops with a cycle time of 10kHz, that repeated at each cycle of the PWM signal to the H-bridges of a class D amplifier, and that controlled the motor current cycle by cycle.  I've done quite a bit in between.

In general, you look at the fastest mode of the system that you're going to control (i.e., motor current, or motor speed, etc.), and you sample faster than that.  The rule of thumb is 10 times, but depending on the precision you need, and the difficulty of attaining high sampling rates, you may sample lower than that or much, much higher (5 is a practical lower limit, there is no practical upper limit, although the required numerical precision of your controller goes up linearly, or possibly as the square of the sampling rate).